# Vimeo api video search results

Tags: vimeo

I am trying to search videos, example here:

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/videos

This is final query:

https://api.vimeo.com/videos?direction=desc&page=1&per_page=10&query=fashion&sort=likes

This returns 10 videos. However if I search using the code:

```
//Search for videos - https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/videos
    $result = $vimeo->request("/videos", array(
                                                    'page'=> $page,
                                                    'per_page' => $perPage,
                                                    'fields' => 'uri,name,description,duration,width,height,privacy,pictures.sizes',
                                                    'sort' => $sort,
                                                    'direction' => $sortDirection,                                      
                                                    'query' => $path
                                                    ));
```

I only get 8 results back, I am not sure why.

The only thing I can see, maybe its not related is that 2 videos that are not returned have this settings:

```
 "privacy": {
            "view": "ptv",
            "embed": "public",
            "download": false,
            "add": false,
            "comments": "nobody"
        },
```

while other have these (I dont know if this matters)

```
"privacy": {
            "view": "anybody",
            "embed": "public",
            "download": false,
            "add": true,
            "comments": "anybody"
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

```
VimeoResponse vimeoResponseList = vimeo.get(VimeoConstants.BASE_URL + "videos?query=" + query + "&sort=date&direction=asc&page=" + connectionProfile.getAgentPropertiesList().get(0));
```

This is look like this --> https://api.vimeo.com/videos?query=asd&sort=date&direction=asc&page=5

This is for java and i use clickntap.